# Why do we have polynomial algorithm to reduce SAT to 3 SAT but not for 3 SAT to 2 SAT?

Tags: algorithm, np, np-complete

I am just trying to understand why can't we reduce 3 SAT to 2 SAT in the same way we reduced general SAT to 3 SAT. Why does it take exponential time in this case?

I know about 2 SAT being in P and 3 SAT being in NP so if we are able to reduce 3 SAT to 2 SAT then effectively we are proving P = NP! But I want to understand the proof for 3 SAT to 2 SAT reduction is not possible in polynomial time.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriate on [cs.se]. In fact there are several discussions there on this exact question, such as https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14596/sat-not-reducible-to-2sat.

Comment: Thank you @beaker. I could find more information in the link provided. :)